# Running Rails mailman + mailer servers on a single Heroku dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I have a Rails application that includes a web server, a Mailman server (to read incoming emails) and a Mailer server (to send out email).

Right now, I have to run each of them on a separate dyno. But I rarely use Mailman and Mailer servers.

Is there a way to combine mailman and mailer together in one dyno?

Comment: You could use something like Mailgun for the mailman and mailer roles.  It converts incoming emails to HTTP POSTs against your webserver and queues up and sends emails via a rest API. I use it for a system that receives about 80,000 emails a month and sends over 250,000 and it works great.

Comment: Thank you, Jason, Mailgun looks brilliant.